# Pandas pivot to bar plot while sorting/preserving sort order from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Int64Index: 125 entries, 0 to 124
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Player          125 non-null object
PTS             125 non-null int64
Value           125 non-null object
FG              125 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2), object(3)
```

I want to build a stacked bar plot, using 'Value' as the legend for the stack (the different parts of the stacked bar), using 'FG' as the value (the size of each part of the stack), using 'Player' as the x-axis label for each item being plotted, and sorting the items by 'PTS'.

I've been able to pivot this data and build a bar plot from it a number of different ways, but none of them will sort properly. If I sort before I pivot, the sort order is lost. I haven't been able to find a way to incorporate the 'PTS' column into the pivot without destroying what I'm doing.

This builds the bar chart I want, but is not sorted (it's not that pretty yet, I can deal with that later):

```
df.pivot(index='Value', columns='Player', values='FG').T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: What's your expected output? Do you want the player to be sorted in `PTS`?

Comment: Can you share some data?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes

Comment: Just curious, how `PTS` plays with `Values` and `FG`. My guess is that `PTS` is the total height of the above bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider creating a list of *Players* before pivoting in descending order by total *PTS* calculated with a `groupby` aggregation. Then use this list in a `reindex` call of columns on the pivoted data:

```
# AGGREGATE POINTS --> SORT --> RETRIEVE INDEX VALUES
sort_list = df.groupby('Player').sum().sort_values('PTS', ascending=False).index

# PIVOT --> REINDEX COLUMNS --> TRANSPOSE & PLOT
(df.pivot(index='Value', columns='Player', values='FG')
   .reindex(sort_list, axis='columns')                     # USING ABOVE SORTED PLAYER LIST
   .T
   .plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
)
```

Comment: I ended up dropping out the PTS column and re-creating it from the FG data anyway, but I tested it and this solution does work, so thank you :)